# Multiaction form by select option with javascript

Tags: javascript, select

```
<form id="check" action="." method="POST">
    <input id="act" type="hidden" name="action"/>
        <select id="blk">
            <option value="blk">Bulk Actions</option>
            <option value="tes">Active</option>
            <option>Inactive</option>
            <option>Delete</option>
        </select>
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('act').value = 'document.getElementById('blk').selectedIndex.value'"/>
</form>
```

i want get the value by select tag and the value action will be change on input with name action as the value

Comment: What will be the in action after selecting an option, as there should be your destination file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed two concepts.

- The `select` element has a `value` property that reflects the current selection

```
document.getElementById('blk').value
```

- The `select` element has a list of options with values and a `selectedIndex` property that reflects the position of the current selection. Use it like this:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('blk');
if (sel.selectedIndex >= 0) // could be -1 as well
    return sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value
```

However, what you actually seem to want is

```
<form id="check" action="." method="POST">
    <select name="action">
         <option value="blk">Bulk Actions</option>
         <option value="tes">Active</option>
         <option>Inactive</option>
         <option>Delete</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

You forgot the `name` of your `select` control, so no value would be posted. With it, you neither need a hidden input nor a click listener on the button (which should have been a `onsubmit` listener on the form as well).

Comment: of course yes, i'm just wanna get change this "<input id="act" type="hidden" name="action"/>" value by select tag, simply with submit button combine

Comment: Yes, then use `onclick="document.getElementById('act').value = document.getElementById('blk').value"` - without `selectedIndex`, and without the apostrophes. Also, you might use an `<input type="button">` for that, your submit button will submit (and reload) the page on-click.

Comment: the value still don't change of value is empty

Comment: How do you know? The input is hidden.

Comment: the actions doesn't show anything, i've index.php for handling action by that value

Comment: Could you show us that file, please? The HTML form in my answer correctly posts the `action` parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
try this
<form id="check" action="." method="POST">
    <input id="act" type="hidden" name="action"/>
        <select id="blk" onchange="javascript:CallMe(this.value)">
            <option value="blk">Bulk Actions</option>
            <option value="tes">Active</option>
            <option>Inactive</option>
            <option>Delete</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('act').value = 'document.getElementById('blk').selectedIndex.value'"/>
</form>

<script>
function CallMe(String str)
{
alert(str+" : is the value selected , call the according action now");
}
</script>
```